# autoset woocommerce orders via stripe payment from status "on hold" to "progress"

Tags: php, woocommerce, stripe-payments

The orders paid via stripe SOFORT and Stripe SEPA are set "on hold" after completing checkout. It will set to "in progress" after a few days when stripe hase verified the payment. I would like to autoset those "on hold" payments from stripe to "in progress" even if stripe hastn verified it yet. I have found the following code but this is vor subscription and SEPA only. Any idea how to modify this?

```
add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_response', 'action_wc_gateway_stripe_regard_sepa_pending_as_complete', 0, 2);
function action_wc_gateway_stripe_regard_sepa_pending_as_complete ($response, $order) {
    // check if Subscriptions are enabled
    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Order' ) ) {
        // check if payment (stripe response) is in pending state
        // check if payment (stripe response) is of 'sepa_debit' type
        // check if order contains a subscription
        if( $response->status === 'pending' && $response->source->type === 'sepa_debit' && function_exists( 'wcs_order_contains_subscription' ) && ( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order->id ) || wcs_is_subscription( $order->id ) || wcs_order_contains_renewal( $order->id ) ) ) {
            $order->payment_complete($response->id);

            /* translators: response id */
            $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Pending status automatically set as payment complete by custom hook (Charge ID: %s)', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ), $response->id ) );
            if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'save' ) ) ) {
                $order->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If in any case `on hold` goes to `unverified` or `fraud` by `stripe` in that case your code will create big issue in system.

Comment: You may be able to use the `payment_method` property of the Order object to infer this: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-properties.

This is mainly business logic in your code you need to figure out. If you want to update the order, here is the API: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-an-order